# "Cannot allocate memory " error whle copying data from window to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

I have Ubuntu 9.10 installed inside VM of server 2008.
WHen i try to copy the data from the network and paste insid ethe Ubuntu it says error

called "Cannot allocate memory "

I have 3GB RAM attached to the Ubuntu

---

I tried above suggestion but still im unbale to copy file from my host machine i.e. Windows XP to my Ubuntu machine ( which is at Virtual Machine)
Im trying to copy jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin file whose size is 47.4 MB

Is there any other work around for this problem????

---

I tried

Set the following registry key to ’1′:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache

and set the following registry key to ’3′:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size

but still im unbale to copy file from my host machine i.e. Windows XP to my Ubuntu machine ( which is at Virtual Machine) Im trying to copy jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin file whose size is 47.4 MB

Is there any other work around for this problem????

Comment: How exactly are you copying and pasting?

Comment: by going in network , clicking on computer icons , and going in folders and then paste in ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Set the following registry key to ’1′:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache
```

and set the following registry key to ’3′:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size
```

After making these changes restart and try again, the error should disappear.

Check [this link](http://alan.lamielle.net/2009/09/03/windows-7-nonpaged-pool-srv-error-2017) .